# Birthdays of all the six persons to fall in only two different months

Tags: probability, combinations

So here is my problem that
To find the probability that the birthdays of all the six persons to fall in only two different months?
There are $12^6$ equally likely sequences, but couldn't move further. Please help

Answer (score 2):

The number of ways in which all the birthdays can fall in January or February is $2^6$.  There are $C(12,2)$ possibilities like this so we get
$$C(12,2)2^6$$
options.  However, there is one case in which all birthdays fall in January, and this has been counted $11$ times (Jan/Feb and Jan/Mar and... and Jan/Dec), so we have to subtract it $10$ times.  And the same goes for each other month.  So the number of possibilities is
$$C(12,2)2^6-12\times10$$
and the probability is
$$\frac{C(12,2)2^6-12\times10}{12^6}\ .$$

**Comment**.  In fact, the $12^6$ possibilities will not be equally likely, (i) because not all months are of the same length, (ii) because births are not evenly distributed across the year.  However, the answer I have given is probably what the question means.